# Установка Firebird на openSUSE 11.4

Tags: opensuse, firebird

Как правильно установить Firebird на openSUSE 11.4?

Поставил пакеты:

- firebird
- firebird-filesystem
- firebird-superserver
- libfbclient2
- libfbembed2

В качестве gui-клиента установил:

- flamerobin

Дальше при попытке создания новой базы и экспорта в неё дампа из файла выдаётся ошибка:

```
Unable to complete network request to host "localhost".
Failed to establish a connection.
Connection refused
```

Что я не сделал или сделал не так?

Comment: Так база вообще запущена? Сетевой сокет включён для использования или только локальный сокет?

Comment: Как это точно проверить можно? К тестовой employee.fdb я подключаюсь нормально, из чего сделал вывод, что всё запущено.

Comment: как именно устанавливал? откуда брал репозитории?

Comment: Устанавливал через Yast, с официальных репозитариев openSUSE (download.opensuse.org).

Answer (score 1):

чере ibexpert с удаленного узла в сети попробуй подключиться, в терминале посмотри не закрыты ли порты netstat -a | grep "tcp 3050"